# Org-mode custom agenda view: WAIT tasks grouped by Assignee

Tags: org-mode

I do have WAIT tasks, and most of all have an Assignee property. For example:

```
** WAIT Receive performance report
   :PROPERTIES:
   :Assignee: john@doe.com
   :END:

** WAIT Get bug #4 fixed
   :PROPERTIES:
   :Assignee: jane@doe.com
   :END:
```

I'd like to get a custom agenda view with all the WAIT tasks grouped by Assignee, such as:

```
Assigned to john@doe.com:
  WAIT Receive performance report
  WAIT Get notes of status meeting

Assigned to jane@doe.com:
  WAIT Get bug #4 fixed
  WAIT Get back book about GTD methodology

Not assigned:
  WAIT Discuss with Sandra when she comes back
```

EDIT (2014-02-23 11:07): The list of assignees is not known, nor static. So, the groups must be discovered when the Org agenda view is generated.

How is such possible?  TIA!

Comment: Here is an example from the documentation that returns hits for a particular property drawer:  `(org-tags-view nil "Assignee={.}")`  However, the sorting and layout would require a custom solution.  See the section in the documentation that states:  `If he would like to pull up all entries that have defined value for the BIB_TITLE property, he can simply use a single dot to match any character: BIB_TITLE={.}`

Comment: The function `org-tags-view` (which uses `org-scan-tags`) takes into account the `org-agenda-skip-function` if it has been defined, so you can use that to focus only on entries containing the word "WAIT".

Comment: See also the section in the manual regarding `org-search-view`, which states:  `Mr. Gnu further finds that to treat 'dog' and 'fox' as boolean keywords that can be located anywhere in the entry, he needs to precede each term with a + . . . . : +fox +dog`  Your boolean keyword search could be:  `+wait +assignee`   However, the sorting and layout (as desired based upon the question hereinabove) would require a custom solution.

Answer (score 0):

**INITIAL ANSWER** (February 22, 2014):  Here is a helpful page from the manual that discusses how to search a property drawer (e.g., `org-tags-view`) and a general search of everything (e.g., `org-search-view`):

http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html

Here is a link to a related thread that contains an alternative method for searching the property drawer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20726532/2112489

Absent modification of the function(s) being used to search the property drawer (and related functions responsible for creating the layout of the `*Org Agenda*` buffer), the display will not look like what the original poster is proposing.

Here is a link to a complex example that is a modification of `org-search-view`, but it would require intermediate `elisp` knowledge to further modify.  The example can be modified to group entries based upon the contents of property drawers -- e.g., *instead of* TASKS, it would be `john@doe.com`; *instead of* EVENTS, it would be `jane@doe.com`; *instead of* UNDATED, it would be `not assigned to anyone`. The applicable property drawer would need a text property added.

https://github.com/lawlist/lawlist-org/blob/master/lawlist-org-agenda.el

---

**EDIT** (February 23, 2014):

Here is an example from the documentation that returns hits for a particular property drawer: `(org-tags-view nil "Assignee={.}")` However, the sorting and layout (as desired based upon the question hereinabove) would require a custom solution. See the section in the documentation that states:  `If he would like to pull up all entries that have defined value for the BIB_TITLE property, he can simply use a single dot to match any character:  BIB_TITLE={.}`

The function `org-tags-view` (which uses `org-scan-tags`) takes into account the `org-agenda-skip-function` if it has been defined, so that can be used to focus only on entries containing the word "WAIT".

See also the section in the manual regarding `org-search-view`, which states:  `Mr. Gnu further finds that to treat 'dog' and 'fox' as boolean keywords that can be located anywhere in the entry, he needs to precede each term with a + . . . . : +fox +dog`  For example, a boolean keyword search could be: `+wait +assignee`  However, the sorting and layout (as desired based upon the question hereinabove) would require a custom solution.  See also, the regexp example in the manual for a todo keyword:   `[+-]Word/{Regexp} ...: +brazil +{^\*+\s-+DONE\s-}`

---

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [lawlist.com](http://www.lawlist.com/images/org_notes_a.png))</sub>

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [lawlist.com](http://www.lawlist.com/images/org_notes_b.png))</sub>

Comment: IIUC, your grouping is static, not dynamic, right?  In my case, I don't know in advance what's the list of current assignees in the Org file (not edited only by me). So, the solution must scan all the possible values first, and then group tasks for each of them (and into "unassigned" for the ones without assignee).

Comment: As well, the fact you give a link to your own version of org-agenda means that this is not doable with the standard Org?

Comment: What you seek is fairly complex and would need to be custom tailored -- org-mode cannot do that out of the box.  The best you can do (without investing substantial time creating a custom solution) is use the examples in the link to the official documentation cited above.  In terms of creating a regexp for an assignee, you could simply use something more broad that would cover all possible e-mail addresses.  My example is just to show what might be possible -- it is how I structure my own calendar / todo-list / contacts, and I synchronize with the Toodledo server for all my computing devices.